# C++ code browser in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, documentation, doxygen

I'm using Eclipse Indigo while programming on c++. I'm using a code that provides extensive doxygen comments. I'd like to be able to see them inside eclipse, without having to use an external browser. I think the javadoc equivalent for that would be `shift+F2`, but it doesn't work with c++ doxygen.

To put it in other words, when my mouse hovers over a method of a class, the tool tip provides the implementation of the function (found in the .cpp), instead of its declaration and the comments associated with it (found in the .h). I would like to see the latter in my tooltip.

Is there a solution for c++ users ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it's **not possible** and I doubt it will be ever possible in future. To explain in detail, read further.
 In C++ you can write a function in 2 ways.

1. Directly define the function (may be `extern`, `inline` or `static`)
2. Declare the function in a header and then define the function in
   implementation file

Now eclipse chooses the implementation always and the reason for that is **consistency**. In C++ (unlike Java) you can have many forward declarations of a function in several header file, however the definition is always **1** (ODR).
If you bring the function under mouse, then which declaration to choose ? So it's better to choose a definition. Though this problem may not occur in the case of class methods.

Coming back to your question:

> the tool tip provides the implementation of the function, instead of
>   its declaration and the comments associated with it

The best way is to have **comments embed with the implementation of the function**. In other words, choose style-2 from below:

### style-1

```
class A {
 ...
public:
  /*
   * description of the function
   */
  void foo ();
};
void A::foo ()
{
...
}
```

### style-2

```
class A {
 ...
public:
  void foo ();
};

/*
 * description of the function
 */
void A::foo ()
{
...
}
```

**Workaround**: Press the `F3` key twice and it will lead you to the declaration via the definition.

Comment: I can't use the style-2 because the doxygen is from an open project, it is not mine, and I can't change all the files of the project. Your explanation seems like a reasonable answer (although as you mentioned class methods probably don't have several declarations). However I am also asking this question from a practical point of view. If it can't be done directly, is there no trick or plugin that would display the appropriate documentation of the method in the tooltip, retrieved either from the hard drive or from the internet documentation ?

Comment: @bob, I am not aware of such plugin. However, if you press '`F3`' and goto the definition of the function then, again you can press '`F3`', that will bring you to the declaration(s) of the function. Mouse hovering may not work.

Comment: Well indeed, pressing F3 twice brings me to where I'm supposed to go. From that observation, would it be difficult to write a plugin that "presses F3 twice", and writes the output of that in the tooltip ? I have no idea how to write plugins, but if it is easy and someone could help me, I might write it. edit: alternatively, to find the comment of the function, there's another path: go to the class of that member, find its definition, and ctrl+f back to the function we were looking for.